# Problem using auto.arima() in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using `auto.arima()` for forecasting. When I am using any in built data such as "AirPassengers" it is capturing seasonality. But, If I am entering data in any other format (in vector form or from an excel sheet) it is not detecting seasonality.

Is there any specific format in which it detects seasonality or I am doing some thing wrong?

Does data have to be entered in a specific format?

Comment: this will be easier to answer if you can provide some sample data where seasonality does not get picked up. Include the results from `dput(myDataWhichDoesNotShowSeasonality)` in the question so we can play along.

Comment: `auto.arima` requires time series to proceed correctly, so just make sure you supply the function with `ts` at needed seasonal frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dmitrij Celov commented, make sure your data is a ts() object, with the proper frequency.  For example, if you have a vector of quarterly data, x = c(4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1), create y=ts(x,frequency=4).  Use frequency=12 for monthly data, etc.

Comment: Zach: I will break my query into 2 parts: 1. My main idea is to give some data as an input and if any seasonality is there in the input, it should be captured automatically and the corresponding frequency automatically generated. please comment whether this is possible with auto.arima() 2. If frequency has to be manually entered to capture seasonality in data. what do we enter if each data point corresponds to a year (I understand ur logic of freq-4 for quaterly data and freq-12 for monthly data). Please comment

Comment: @Siddharth: 1. It is not possible. 2. If each point corresponds to a year, you can still determine a frequency.  For example, if you think there is a decade-long seasonality you can set frequency=10.  Maybe you should ask a separate question along the lines of "How can I automatically detect the seasonality of a time series if it is not already known"

Answer (score 0):

convert to ts, ts(x, start=c(2006,10), freq=12)